# Commit pushed but cannot see it anywhere on the repo

Tags: git

Please help me, I lost the work of the 4 last days.

I was working on a branch, say branch-a

I did

```
git add .

git commit -m "......"
```

Then I got

```
git commit -m "......"
[branch-a c570a27] ......
55 files changed, 538 insertions(+), 333 deletions(-)
///more here of all files changed
```

Then I did

```
git push origin master
```

(being on branch-a, I figured it would still push to master) Then I got this on the console

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/rsbix/website.git
   7da90b9..1da7015  master -> master
```

After this, the changes were not live, so I figured they were on branch-a instead of master

So I did

```
git reset --hard origin/branch-a
```

And lost everything. New changes are not there

So then I went on to do

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

All is lost

This specific commit 7da90b9..1da7015, I don't see on the repo, I can't find it, and can't reset to it because the numbers are incomplete on the console response

When I do git log the last commit is not there either

Comment: @torek sorry, it's a typo. I'll fix it now. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) provides you with a history of your local git commits.

The wording is quite difficult to understand so I've put both flows below (or perhaps you'll need a bit of both).

Flow 1, assuming you have the correct stuff locally but have now 'lost' it:

First, run `git reflog` to find the SHA of the commit you want to go back to. Copy the SHA. Then run a standard `git reset --hard <SHA>` to go back to that point in time.

Once you've rebuilt your branches locally, `git push` them to the appropriate place, you may need to force push,

Flow 2, everything is correct remotely but you've pulled it to the wrong place locally:

To find the code you've just pushed to your remote, run `git fetch` and then `git branch -r` will show you a list of remote branches prefixed with `origin/`.

Find the 'correct' branch and pull that.

---

As a general rule, stop tinkering with `git reset --hard` unless you are absolutely 100% sure you know what you're doing. Better to checkout a SHA to a new branch.